# Can I overload operator[][]?

Tags: c++, operators

I'm writing a `Matrix` type, and I would like the following code to define a `2,2` integer matrix, put its first element at 3, and throw an exception upon reaching the third line:

```
Matrix<int> a(2,2);
a[0][0] = 3;
int b = a[10][28];
```

For this, I need to overload "`operator[][]`". Let me explain further:

- My matrix is defined as a template with parameter type `T` and stores its elements in a 2-dimensional array defined as  `T** content`.
- My point in overloading "`operator[][]`" is to avoid an access violation and throw an exception that can be handled afterwards (an access violation is **not** an exception).
- Overloading  `operator[]` once would allow me to use `a[0]` and `a[0]` would return a `T*` type.
- To overload the "`operator[][]`" of `Matrix`, I actually need to overload the `operator[]` of my aforementioned `T*` return type.
- Since `T*` is an array, its `operator[]` is already defined and working fine, so there's no point in changing it.
- Even if I did, I could not do anything relevant to my point because it is outside of the `Matrix` class.

How can I work this out?
I could make the first `operator[]` overload return a new `MatrixRow` object which I can work further with, but is it not a pretty heavy solution?

Comment: You already answered your own question... and a `MatrixRow` object is only as heavy as you make it, if it contains a copy of the whole row it will be expensive, but if it just points into the bigger matrix, it is as cheap to make as `T*`.  Probably the reality is somewhere in the middle, you need a `T*` and a `size_t` to check the `MatrixRow::operator[]()` argument against.  Another option is defining `Matrix::operator()(int row, int col)`.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6969881/103167 (also check the list of linked questions on that page)

Comment: @BenVoigt Ok I will dig into that thanks for the precisions! But it's curious, the question you mentioned didn't show up when I looked for it.

Comment: Another example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2216055/179910

Comment: The `MatrixRow` object is an example of [a proxy object in C++](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Temporary_Proxy). For example, `std::vector<bool>::operator[]` returns a temporary proxy. Provided that the compiler is able to completely inline the creation, use, and destruction of the proxy object, it is possible that the compiler can transform the code so that the equivalent behavior is accomplished without actually having to create any object that consumes memory. Be sure to use appropriate optimization flags and verify the compiled disassembly.

Comment: @rwong That's good to know. And very interesting too. I knew that compiler optimizations could sometimes be mind-blowingly smart, and this is just another example. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `operator[][]` in C++.  When using multidimensional indices, `operator[]` is applied in sequence to the result of the previous one.

Example:  `a[i][j]`  applies `operator[](i)` to `a`.  It then applies `operator[](j)` to the result.

Now there are at least 4 ways to solve your problem:

- overload `operator[]()` with an object that combines both coordinates, for example by packing them into a pair with `operator[] (pair<size_t, size_t>)`.  This is nice in theory, but makes indexing look clumsy.
- overload `operator[]` to return a reference to an object that represents the row (e.g. `MatrixRow`), and with itself has an appropriate `operator[]`.  This is a very clean approach. However, it requires the `Matrix` to be an aggregate of `MatrixRow` (because you need to be able to return a reference to it).  Unfortunately, this is now always possible (e.g. some sparse matrix structures use compression schemes that do not allow a directly addressable row object).

  ***Update:*** A variant of this approach could be to return a proxy object for the row instead of a reference. This is a little bit trickier because the proxy has to emulate the behavior of a row reference (see discussion in the comments) and it still needs a class to represent a full matrix row for this purpose.  However, the additional complexity comes with the advantage of decoupling the internal representation of the matrix from the representation of a full row. (Thanks [Angew](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/109526/angew) for this suggestion)
- expose the inner details of your implementation, by returning directly the pointer to the array.  While this is very comfortable, it's really not a clean design, because you create a dependency of the using code to the inner details of your Matrix.
- overload `operator()` , which allows for multiple parameters.  The main issue here is to et accustomed to the use of `()` instead of `[]`.  If you go for this, you'd better not define an operator[] for the Matrix, just to avoid some subtle errors that might arise when accidentally combining `[]` with the use of the coma operator.

One question though:  why do you still use arrays, when you could more safely use vectors instead ?

Example of the last approach:

```
template <class T>
class Matrix {
    vector<vector<T>> m; 
public: 
    Matrix (int r, int c) : m(r, vector<int>(c, T())) { }
    T& operator() (int r, int c) { return m[r][c]; }
    ...
};

Matrix a(2,2); 
a(1,0) = 5;
int e = a(1,0);
```

For more examples (using 3 of the 4 discussed approaches), see [online demo](http://ideone.com/fgWG2T).

Comment: I went with the second way, I used a `MatrixRow` object and it's working fine now. As for why I use arrays instead of vectors, the short answer is that I enjoy doing everything from scratch, and encountering problems like this one makes me able to solve them faster afterwards. The long answer is, I want to make my code as light as possible, even if it means only having the bare functionality, which is okay since it is going to be used by me only. :)

Comment: WRT the akwardness of `matrix[make_pair(r,c)]`: I expect that `matrix[{r,c}]` works in C++17.

Comment: @Sjoerd shouldn't this already work in c++14 ? But playing with [{ }] as in the online demo shows that it'll be easy to forget a pair. Option 2 or 4 seem therefore better suited imho

Comment: @Christophe Yes, could be C++14 already. And you're right that forgetting the {} in `a[{1,2}]` would cause `a[1,2]` to be interpreted as `a[2]`. However, when there is no overload for operator[](int) that should result in a compiler error, but it will be a bit cryptic.

Comment: `vector<vector<T>> m;` DON'T do that. PLEASE. It not only creates unnecessary vectors (waste of space, time for allocation and has poor locality) but also allows to have a non-rectangular array which is unneeded. Just use std::unique_ptr<T[]> and make a custom address computing function.

Comment: @Sopel interesting remark. My last addressing option based on operator() could work also with your scheme, because it completely encapsulates the 2D addressing. However, i let it open to OP to decides what's best for him: if he routinely works with full rows or if he's refactoring an app with lots of 2d array style addressing, i'd keep the vector of vectors. By the way, if i were to implement your approach of flattening the matrix, i'd rather use a private 1d vector rather than a unique_ptr to a 1d array: it would spare the implementation of a custom copy constructor, and assignment operator.

Comment: It is possible to make custom row and column iterators working with a single array. So you don't really lose anything by that approach.

Comment: Why would solution 2 require returning a reference? You can just as well return a temporary (proxy object) with `operator[]` defined.

Comment: @Angew your proposal is certainly an alternative to explore.  However, if you want to keep semantic consistency, your proxy object should allow use on the left side of an assignment (full row assignments that changes the matrix) as well as on the right side (value of full row).  This is certainly feasible but quite tricky (i.e. keep a link to the original matrix, overloading the assignment operator to update the original matrix, foresee a conversion operator to full row, etc...) and will anyway need a class to represent a full row (to define the aforementioned overloads/conversions).

Comment: @Christophe Still, it's better to overload the few operators than to need to keep these proxy-like objects in the matrix itself. As comments on the question say, e.g. `std::vector<bool>` uses exactly such a temporary proxy. I just felt like "return a proxy" was quite an obvious solution missing from the list, I don't claim it's the only or superior alternative.

Comment: @Angew True !  Thanks for the suggestion: I've updated the answer